# How can I instantiate new instance of some class given that I already have object of that class?

Tags: clojure

I'm new to `clojure`, my question is really simple but stumble me.
I want to Instantiate a class get by `class`, looks like:

```
(new (class an-object))
```

Just get the instance initialize by nothing.

For example, If the `an-object` is a vector:

```
(new (class [1 2 3]))
```

I run this in `repl` but only get the error message:

> CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to
>   resolve classname: (class []), compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1)

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Instantiate some class, when you have `Class[..]` object or what?

Comment: @om-nom-nom Yes, assume that I have an object and want instantiate the class of the object.

Comment: People down-voting: Clojure developers don't always have a Java background, and so the answer to this question may not be obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the covers it's all Java, so you will have to abide by the limitations of Java reflection.

`PersistentVector` [doesn't have a default constructor](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentVector.java), so `(new (class [1 2 3]))` won't ever work. You'd need to inspect the constructors and static methods available and use those.

Also, here is a function (not a macro) that works for classes with zero arg constructors, kind of what you're trying to do (well, `defn` is a macro, so ` and ~ work, but that's another story):

```
(defn new-instance [obj & args]
  (let [clazz (class obj)]
    (eval `(new ~clazz ~@args))))

=> (new-instance "1224")
""
=> (new-instance (new java.util.HashMap))
{}

;; can even pass arguments to constructors
=> (new-instance 1234 "42")
42
```

Comment: I find the public static method `create` and run `(clojure.lang.PersistentVector/create 1)`, only get error message: IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: create

Comment: Clojure is very, very strict about matching parameters. There is no signature `create(Long 1)` so it doesn't work. This does work: `(clojure.lang.PersistentVector/create (list 1))`

Answer (score 2):

I came across a similar issue where I wanted to pass a `Class` to a function when dealing with java interop. The ["." dot special form](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop#_the_dot_special_form) is a bit more flexible than `new` and you can use it to avoid `eval` or a macro

```clj
(defn new-instance
  ([clazz]
   (. clazz newInstance))
  ([clazz args]
   (new-instance clazz (map class args) args))
  ([clazz ctor-classes args]
   (->
    (. clazz getConstructor (into-array Class ctor-classes))
    (.newInstance (into-array Object args)))))


(comment
  (new-instance String)
  ;;=> ""
  (new-instance (class "abc"))
  ;;=> ""
  (new-instance String ["foo"])
  ;;=> "foo"
  (new-instance Long [String] ["11"])
  ;;=> 11
  (new-instance Long [Long/TYPE] [42]) ; special case for primitive types
  ;;=> 11
  (new-instance java.io.File [(clojure.java.io/file "/tmp") "test.txt"])
  ;;=> #object[java.io.File 0x5c69702f "/tmp/test.txt"]
  (new-instance java.io.File ["/tmp" "test2.txt"])
  ;;=> #object[java.io.File 0x39859951 "/tmp/test2.txt"]
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an error has nothing to do with constructors.

The real reason it does not work is because `new` is a [special form](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababa.htm), and not a function application. Unlike a function application, which evaluate arguments eagerly, `new` does not.

It expects a single symbol as argument, and resolves the Classname from it.

As you can see, `(class an-object)` is not a symbol, but a list of 2 symbols. Therefore it fails.

The reason [noahlz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16242588/244935) solves this, is because the symbol for the classname is calculated in the `let` block separately. Then the correct expression with `new` is put together in a `quote`, and then `eval`-uated. All this behind lambda abstraction, so it can be called on-demand.

**Takeaway:**

The real problem was that `new` is a special form, and needs a symbol constant as argument.